# Multi camera detection issue (not detected)

Tags: linux, image-processing, camera, real-time, 360-panorama

I am trying to set a multi camera in my computer on Linux 14.04.

In fact, the name of the camera is LadyBug5.

https://www.ptgrey.com/ladybug5-360-degree-usb3-spherical-camera-systems

after the different configuration of drivers, I got this message in terminal, saying that I cannot detect the camera as desired :

```
zac@zac:~/catkin_ws/src/ladybugcapture$ LadybugRecorderConsole 
Loading configuration from /etc/ladybug/LadybugRecorderConsole.xml
*** Configuration ***
Camera Configuration
Data format: JPEG (8-bit)
Frame rate: 10
Use auto frame rate: Yes
JPEG quality: 80%
GPS Configuration
Use GPS: No
Port: 4
Device name: dev/ttyACM0
Baud rate: 115200
Refresh interval (ms): 1000
Stream Configuration
Destination directory: .


Cameras detected: 0

Insufficient number of cameras detected.
Error: Failed to initialize camera (Operation failed)
```

Do you have any tips to resolve this problem?

thanking you in advance

Answer (score 0):

My first question is: is the camera recognized by the linux kernel? Detach the camera from the computer, run `dmesg` command, then atach the camera to your computer and run `dmesg` agin. The new lines at the end of the output should give a first hint if the camera is recognized at all.
After this try the `lsusb` command to see if the USB subsystem has access to the camera.
If it looks fine, then you could have a problem with the access rights to the camera's USB system. Can you try to run the `LadybugRecorderConsole` command with root privileges, e.g. `sudo LadybugRecorderConsole`?

Comment: thank you for your answer. In fact, I already tried to run dmesg,  and I found that the camera Ladybug is recognized by the linux Kernel without any problem. tomorrow I am gonna try with sudo LadybugRecorderConsole, and I'll let u know ! thank you in advance.

Comment: well, I got a good result, i could detect the camera but I got also an error in the end of the code. Cameras detected: 1

Camera information: 
Base s/n: 15295511
Head s/n: 15295511
Model: Ladybug5 LD5-U3-51S5C-44
Sensor: Sony ICX655 (2/3" 2048x2448 CCD)
Vendor: Point Grey Research
Bus / Node: 0 / 0

Error: Failed to initialize stream (Operation failed)

Comment: That seems more like a problem in the software itself. With this you should contact the manufacturer. Maybe the linux software still has some bugs/problems? Or you could have more success with a more recent linux version?  Ubuntu 14.04 is pretty old...